# How to deploy NestJs app with mongodb into AWS ECS Fargate

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker, nestjs, amazon-ecs

I have a problem with deploying my nestjs + mongodb app into AWS ECS. I'm using docker compose file. I have 2 build in docker compose: dev and prod. Both versions are working well locally. The problem is with deploying to ECS Fargate. I'm pushing app and mongo images into AWS ECR. Based on them I made a task running 2 containers - app and mongo. I opened ports in security group. After running the task, I can connect to mongodb via public ip, but I can't connect to the app. The app is trying to connect mongodb, but finally the error pop up - hostname not found. I've tested it with all cases and to be honest I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Dockerfile

```
###################
# BUILD FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY --chown=node:node . .

USER node

###################
# BUILD FOR PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

COPY --chown=node:node --from=development /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY --chown=node:node . .  

RUN npm run build

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN npm ci --only=production && npm cache clean --force

USER node

###################
# PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  dev:
    container_name: animals_api_dev
    image: animals-api-dev:1.0.0
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: npm run start:debug
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=${MONGO_HOST}
      - MONGO_PORT=${MONGO_PORT}
      - MONGO_USERNAME=${MONGO_USERNAME}
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - animals-api-network
    depends_on:
      - mongo-database
      - mongo-express
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    restart: unless-stopped

  prod:
    container_name: animals_api_prod
    image: animals-api-prod:1.00
    build:
      context: .
      target: production
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: npm run start:prod
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=${MONGO_HOST}
      - MONGO_PORT=${MONGO_PORT}
      - MONGO_USERNAME=${MONGO_USERNAME}
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
    networks:
      - animals-api-network
    depends_on:
      - mongo-database
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    restart: unless-stopped

  mongo-database:
    container_name: animals-mongo-db
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27018:${MONGO_PORT}
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_USERNAME}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - animals-api-network

  mongo-express:
    container_name: animals-mongo-express
    image: mongo-express:latest
    ports:
      - ${MONGO_EXPRESS_PORT}:${MONGO_EXPRESS_PORT}
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=${MONGO_USERNAME}
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=${MONGO_PASSWORD}
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=animals-mongo-db
    depends_on:
      - mongo-database
    networks:
      - animals-api-network
    restart: unless-stopped

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis-cache
    ports:
      - ${REDIS_PORT}:${REDIS_PORT}
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
    networks:
      - animals-api-network

networks:
  animals-api-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongo-data:
  redis:
```

Comment: I don't think you are setting the environment variables correctly. I would look at the ECS task definition in the AWS web console to verify what values are being set for the environment variables.

Comment: for mongo task i'm setting the same as in docker compose file - mongo-database and in app task the same as in docker compose - prod

Comment: @MarkB you have been right... env variables were incorrect, MONGO_HOST shouldd be diffrent then mongo container name. I've put 127.0.0.1 and it worked.
I've found out that in Fargate link is not working